# How to write entity in relationship using JpaItemWriter in Spring Batch

Tags: hibernate

Situation:

I have class A which I read from db with JpaPagingItemReader.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="...")
public class ClassA {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FKID_ClassB")
    private ClassB classB;
```

In the processor a new class B (which is referenced by a foreign key in class A) will be created.
In addition, the item from table A will be updated.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="...")
public class ClassB {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy ="classB")
    private List<ClassA> classAs;
```

Problem:
The writer should be able to write at the same time all items, but exception occurs while writing class A with JpaItemWriter:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: my.package.ClassA.classB -> my.package.ClassB
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1384)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:999)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter.write(JpaItemWriter.java:85)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:141)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:151)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:130)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
```

This is my configuration:

```xml
<batch:job id="myJob">
    <batch:step id="myStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManagerDb">
            <batch:chunk reader="myReader" processor="myCompositeProcessor"
                writer="myWriter" commit-interval="${myJob.commitInterval}"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="myReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryDb" />
    <property name="queryString"
                        value="select d from Class A d where...." />
    <property name="pageSize" value="${myJob.commitInterval}" />
</bean>

<bean id="myWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryDb" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` or save `ClassB` before you set it to `ClassA`.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="FKID_ClassB")
private ClassB classB;
```